# Error NoClassDefFoundError/ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

after about a month of not opening eclipse at all, I get a strange error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Z
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Z
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

I don't really understand what it wants, it doesn't show me anything else, something about main class "Z" not being defined? but it is, isn't it?

[CODE][/CODE] doesn't work very well here so I'll put source here: http://pastebin.com/heMhDqU2

Thank you.

Edit 1: it shows me when I try to compile and run. Btw, indent code by using 4 spaces for 500 lines... seems kinda reduntant

Comment: Is this when starting Eclipse or when starting your program?

Comment: Also, you can insert code into questions, just like you inserted the exception stacktrace. The question editor even has a button to indent a block of text so it's recognised as code.

Comment: Sorry but wtf about your code.

Comment: I stopped reading your code at line 54.... seriously, grow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine it compiles here.

Most probably an eclipse error.
Try this.

1. Close eclipse
2. Start eclipse with the flag .../eclipse.exe -clean
3. Press Project -- > Clean

Comment: I just reinstalled eclipse, I don't know when or how it got broken, but thanks anyway, can be closed.